# TypeScript: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

```
const FormInput: FC<IFormInputProps> = ({ name, label, ...otherProps }) => {

  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller control={control} defaultValue='' name={name} render={({ field }) => (
        <FormControl>
          <Typography>{label}</Typography>
          <Input {...field} error={!!errors[name]} {...otherProps} />
          <FormHelperText error={!!errors[name]}>
            {errors[name] ? errors[name].message : ''}
          </FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default FormInput
```

TypeScript ругается на вывод сообщения `{errors[name] ? errors[name].message : ''}`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как победить?

Comment: А почему бы не сделать `{errors[name] !== undefined && errors[name].message}`?

Comment: Все же написано в описании ошибки `Type 'string |...' is not assignable to type ReactNode` и так далее

Comment: {errors[name] !== undefined && errors[name].message} результат тот же самый ((
Я не силён в JS, поэтому сильно не ругайте

Comment: Если делаю с вопросом `{errors[name] ? errors[name]?.message : ''}`, то остается только первая ошибка: `TS2769: No overload matches this call.`